# Installation of SQL*Plus and SQL Server Management Studio into Windows Tablet

Tags: oracle, windows

I would like to check if SQL*Plus client and Microsoft SQL Server Management studio (SSMS) are supported in Windows(8.1) tablet? `Windows tablets such as Asus or Lenovo MII3/thinkpad 8 comes with Windows 8.1 Bing.`

Comment: if your tablet is running Windows 8, then the oracle client/SQL*Plus should work. if your table can support a java JRE, then our new SQL*Plus, SQLcl (a 12MB download) should work if you have a command window/shell for your OS

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Good to see you on here!